# Connect two ethernet sockets to each other

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, home-networking, gigabit-ethernet

I have an ethernet wall socket that has two ports, looks pretty much like this: [image]

My router feeds the left port (from the back), and I have another computer which is connected to the right port, and I want the computer to receive the signal from the router.

See the following drawing:

[image]

In the drawing above you can see the router is connected (through the wall) to the back of port `A`. The back of port `B` is connected (through the wall) to the back of port `C`. The computer is connected to the front of port `C`. The *`CABLE`* that would connect port `A` and `B` from the front is my question.

Can I connect the left port to the right port with a simple ethernet cable so that my computer will be connected to my router? Will I need to use a special cable for that? I tried connecting with just a normal ethernet cable and it doesn't work and I'm wondering if it's a problem in some other part of the connection (inside the wall).

Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully "pretty much like this" doesn't include having only four pins in the middle...

Comment: Indeed, it's just a random pic I found. Any thoughts?

Comment: Assuming proper connections, an ordinary patch cable should work.  Since you indicate you cannot get a connection, then you need to test each individual cable segment.  (That's when having a long, e.g. 75' cable, comes in handy to span any two rooms in the house).  I'd start with a simple connection between just the router & PC to validate *each* patch cable that you're going to use.  Then insert the 'C' in-wall segment into the path.  Then insert the 'B' segment.  Test just the 'A' segment.  Then test 'A' + 'B'.